# What is a good site to explore all of the different print materials?

Tags: print-design, print-production, resource-recommendations

I am new to design and looking to get more familiar with different materials available to print on, different paper weights, learn about vinyls, etc. Does anyone know of some good sources to learn more about this?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but there is some relevant info here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/80227/physical-paper-weight-reference/80239#80239

Answer (score 1):

Modern machines can print on pretty much anything, the best thing to do is find a **local print supplier** and have a look at some items they produced. Some large printers can send you actual [samples of different material](https://www.psprint.com/samples1005/index.asp).

Another thing you can do is look for a **[trade show](http://www.seexpo.com/index.php/index/Search/industry/fid/90/sid/370)** in your area, these are multi-day events where all these providers and equipment makers will show off their tools and techniques. There will possibly be seminars and live demos you can attend. The [Inprint](http://www.inprintshow.com/germany/english/inprint/photos/) trade show in Munich, Germany is one good example.

One thing i did recently was order a **free business card sample pack** from [Moo](https://www.moo.com/uk/free-sample-business-cards.html) which includes different types of paper and other finishes like varnish, silver layer, gold finish, etc.